# PInvoke for GlobalMemoryStatusEx on Windows CE

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

Do not vote this down if you don't work on or know about Windows CE and the Compact Framework. Thanks.

Anybody know if this function is available on WinCE and (if so) what the DLL is? I've tried to PInvoke this from "coredll.dll" and "kernel.dll". The Win32 version comes from "kernel32.dll".

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("kernel.dll")] // and "coredll.dll" also doesn't work
public static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx([In,Out] MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);
```

The above function fails when I try and use it with an exception "Can't find PInvoke DLL 'kernel.dll'."

PS: I use loads of PInvoked functions such as this one:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int nMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only the [GlobalMemoryStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885649.aspx) call, not the extended (...Ex) version. It is located in coredll.dll, see http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.GlobalMemoryStatus

Answer (score 2):

Have implemented the answer suggested by C.Evenhuis and it works well. Here's the code for anyone who might need this in future:

```
// Structure to allow getting memory usage
public struct MEMORYSTATUS
{
        public int nLength;
        public int nMemoryLoad;
        public uint uTotalPhys;
        public uint uAvailPhys;
        public uint uTotalPageFile;
        public uint uAvailPageFile;
        public uint uTotalVirtual;
        public uint uAvailVirtual;
}

[DllImport("coredll", EntryPoint="GlobalMemoryStatus", SetLastError = false)]
public static extern void GlobalMemoryStatus(out MEMORYSTATUS memCE);

MEMORYSTATUS mem = new MEMORYSTATUS();
mem.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MEMORYSTATUS));
GlobalMemoryStatus(out mem);
// Label1.Text = (mem.uAvailPhys.ToString() + "Bytes");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using in this way.

```
/// <summary>
/// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488368.aspx
/// This structure contains information about current memory availability. The GlobalMemoryStatus function uses this structure.
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MemoryStatus
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the size, in bytes, of the MEMORYSTATUS structure.
    /// Set this member to sizeof(MEMORYSTATUS) when passing it to the GlobalMemoryStatus function.
    /// </summary>
    public int Length;
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies a number between zero and 100 that gives a general idea of current memory use, in which zero indicates no memory use and 100 indicates full memory use.
    /// </summary>
    public uint MemoryLoad;
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates the total number of bytes of physical memory.
    /// </summary>
    public uint TotalPhys;
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates the number of bytes of physical memory available.
    /// </summary>
    public uint AvailPhys;
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates the total number of bytes that can be stored in the paging file.
    /// This number does not represent the physical size of the paging file on disk.
    /// </summary>
    public uint TotalPageFile;
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates the number of bytes available in the paging file.
    /// </summary>
    public uint AvailPageFile;
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates the total number of bytes that can be described in the user mode portion of the virtual address space of the calling process.
    /// </summary>
    public uint TotalVirtual;
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates the number of bytes of unreserved and uncommitted memory in the user mode portion of the virtual address space of the calling process.
    /// </summary>
    public uint AvailVirtual;
    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    private static extern void GlobalMemoryStatus(ref MemoryStatus ms);
    public static string GetMemoryStatus()
    {
        var retValue = new StringBuilder();
        MemoryStatus ms = GlobalMemoryStatus();
        retValue.AppendLine(string.Format("Memory Load {0} %", ms.MemoryLoad));
        retValue.AppendLine(string.Format("Total Phys {0} Kb", ms.TotalPhys / 1024));
        retValue.AppendLine(string.Format("Avail Phys {0} Kb", ms.AvailPhys / 1024));
        retValue.AppendLine(string.Format("Tota PFile {0} bytes", ms.TotalPageFile));
        retValue.AppendLine(string.Format("Avai PFile {0} bytes", ms.AvailPageFile));
        retValue.AppendLine(string.Format("Total Virt {0} Kb", ms.TotalVirtual / 1024));
        retValue.AppendLine(string.Format("Avail Virt {0} Kb", ms.AvailVirtual / 1024));
        return retValue.ToString();
    }

    public static MemoryStatus GlobalMemoryStatus()
    {
        MemoryStatus ms = new MemoryStatus();
        ms.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(ms);
        GlobalMemoryStatus(ref ms);
        return ms;
    }
    public static uint GetMemoryLoad()
    {
        var ms = GlobalMemoryStatus();
        return ms.MemoryLoad;
    }
}
```

[image: string memory = Device.MemoryStatus.GetMemoryStatus(); MessageBox.Show(memory, "Memory");]

You can check in WinBase.h of your Windows CE SDK

```
typedef struct _MEMORYSTATUS {
    DWORD dwLength;
    DWORD dwMemoryLoad;
    DWORD dwTotalPhys;
    DWORD dwAvailPhys;
    DWORD dwTotalPageFile;
    DWORD dwAvailPageFile;
    DWORD dwTotalVirtual;
    DWORD dwAvailVirtual;
} MEMORYSTATUS, *LPMEMORYSTATUS;

VOID
WINAPI
GlobalMemoryStatus(
    __inout LPMEMORYSTATUS lpBuffer
    );
```

Because is **_inout** in SDK. I have used "**ref**" parameter modifier.

this is all about.